# Do arguments get copied if they're stored

Tags: c++

Are arguments copied if they are stored in the following cases

Literal string passed:

```
std::string globalStr;
void store(const std::string &str)
{
    globalStr = str;
}
store("Literal");
```

Variable string passed:

```
std::string globalStr;
void store(const std::string &str)
{
    globalStr = str;
}
store(varStr);
```

And what if globalStr stores reference

```
std::string &globalStr;
void store(const std::string &str)
{
    globalStr = str;
}
store("Literal"); //Should this cause any problem?
store(varStr);
```

Does C++ optimize to prevent making unnecessary copies in any of the above cases?

Answer (score 1):

> Does C++ optimize to prevent making unnecessary copies in any of the above cases?

No.

The stardard just guarantees that, in the 1st and 2nd cases, the value of `str` will be copied to `globalStr`, using `std::string::operator=()`.

Depending on the implementation of your STL, if `std::string` uses a copy-on-write optimization, a deep copy might be avoided.

The 3rd case will not compile, as a reference cannot be reassigned after it has been initialized.

Comment: The reference would also have to be assigned at construction

Answer (score 1):

In the first two examples, you are binding a reference: `void store(const std::string &str)`, that in itself does *not* copy.

But in the statement where you are *assigning* to a global variable: `globalStr = str;` - It *does* make a copy of it.

In your third example this does not compile: `std::string &globalStr;` - reference needs to be initialized!

You can try to set up for a move by writing:

```
void store(std::string &&str)
{
    globalStr = std::move(str);
}
store(std::move(varStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

As in any case involving compiler optimization: it depends on the compiler.

If the compiler is programmed to (and can in the situation given to it) prove to itself that a copy is unnecessary, it won't perform that copy.

For your particular question, neither of the first two methods could perform unnecessary copies anyway, because the inputs are passed by reference into the `store` function. They are copied when you assign them to `globalStr`, but that copy is *necessary* because `globalStr` is a value variable; it is its own copy, and therefore cannot point to some other copy.

And this line:

```
std::string &globalStr;
```

can't compile. A reference must be assigned something to refer to at the time it is declared.